# Find the rank of a smooth map between general linear group.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, general-linear-group

> Consider a smooth map $f$:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f: GL(2n,\mathbb{R})&\to GL(2n,\mathbb{R})\\
> A&\mapsto AJA^{\text{T}},
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> J=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> -I_n& \\
> &I_n\\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$is a $2n\times 2n$ matrix. 
>   Find the rank of $f$.

I have ever tried to calculate it by using the tangent map of $f$ to show the rank of $f$, because $\mathrm{rank}f_*= \mathrm{rank}f$. But I failed to write the representation of the linear map $f_*$. So, I will appreciate it if someone can give me an effective idea about this question.

Thanks.